# Elasticsearch : adding temporary field to result with Groovy

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I've a large configuration with queries and filters, which works fine.

Now, I'm adding a new script filter with Groovy, which works fine too:

```
doc['age'].value >= 18;
```

> But I'm wondering how to do the following with Groovy:
>
> Add a temporary boolean field to current document. See example below.

Example document in my result:

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "age": 20
}
```

But I want to add the result of the script filter in my result, like so:

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "age": 20,
    "age_ok": true
}
```

`age_ok` is not indexed, but set by the Groovy filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, You can't inject a script filter into the search result, but you can use scriptable field in order to inject scriptable data. You'll have to duplicate some part of the script.

From the documentation :

```
{
    "query" : {
        ...
    },
    "script_fields" : {
        "test1" : {
            "script" : "doc['my_field_name'].value * 2"
        },
        "test2" : {
            "script" : {
                "inline": "doc['my_field_name'].value * factor",
                "params" : {
                    "factor"  : 2.0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html